# C# Sum Value From Foreach

Tags: c#, sql, razor, sum

So Im doing a cshtml website and I cant seem to figure out how to sum the product of each row from the database and the foreach!

```
var db = Database.Open("TestDB");
var getData = "SELECT * FROM Test";
```

and then

```
@foreach (var get in db.Query(getData)) {
    <a>@get.kg</a> 
    <a>@get.set</a> 
    <a>@get.rep</a>
    //So this row gives me the product of each row in the database
    @(get.kg * get.set * get.rep)            
    <br>
}
```

But I then want to sum up all the totals to a big total! Dont know how to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My cshtml is a bit rusty, but I think this would do the trick in a pinch for you:

```
@{ var sumTotalWeight = 0 }
@foreach (var get in db.Query(getData)) {
    <a>@get.kg</a> 
    <a>@get.set</a> 
    <a>@get.rep</a>
    @{
       var totalWeight = @get.kg * @get.set * @get.rep;
       sumTotalWeight += totalWeight
    }
    <br>
}

@sumTotalWeight
```

Really the better way to handle this though is to do your calculations and math in your code behind and putting your values in the ViewBag - this keeps your UI code cleaner:

```
var query = @"SELECT kg, set, rep, kg*set*rep as 'total' FROM Test";
using (var db = Database.Open("TestDB"))
{
    // .ToArray() to materialize the query;
    ViewBag.Items = db.Query(query).ToArray();
    // you might need to cast to ints (i'm not sure)
    ViewBag.SumTotal = ViewBag.Items.Sum(i => (i.total));
}
```

Then in your `cshtml`:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Items) {
    <a>@item.kg</a> 
    <a>@item.set</a> 
    <a>@item.rep</a>
    @item.total            
    <br>
}
Total: @ViewBag.SumTotal
```

Comment: the second better alternative didnt really work, it says the name ViewBag doesnt exist in the current context! refering to this row:

ViewBag.Items = db.Query(query).ToArray();

Comment: Can you elaborate what is happening when you say "happening without success"? Also, can you edit your question to include your controller. ViewBag is part of ControllerBase - so I'm unclear why that would be missing unless you are running this code somewhere not in the controller.

Comment: The first solution did what I did in the code in the question it multiplied the values on the same row to a total, and does that for all rows, so every row includes a total sum, however, id like to sum all those total sum to one big sum at the end! And also, Im not doing MVC, just html and razor at the top of the cshtml files, Im just doing a small private site for self use as I found that doing a webpage would be easier than a c# program with the knowlegde I have, and I coulnt find a good mvc tutorial, made very little sense to me! I'll update the code after work if u wanna give it a shot

Comment: Ah, I made a slight edit.. to remove the `@totalWeight` from the loop - What is the totalWeight printing at the end? Does it print what you'd expect? It would help if You could paste the output and then show me what the corrected output should look like. Also, ok, understand no ViewBag - no problem.

Comment: Just got home now to test it! Works abolutely perfect! I've checked that the calculations are correct so thats awesome! I hugely appreciate your help! Thank you very much!